# Understanding offset-k method of representing negative integers

Tags: binary

I'm reading [this article](https://vineetgupta22.wordpress.com/tag/offset-binary-representation/) about offset-k method of representing negative integers. Can someone please explain the following passage using some examples:

> One logical way to represent signed integers is to have enough range
>   in binary numbers so that the zero can be offset to the middle of the
>   range of positive binary numbers. Then the magnitude of a negative
>   binary number can be simply subtracted from that zero point.

I understand the mechanics, e.g. to represent number 4 in 11 bits, I'll do `4+1023=1027`, but can't understand the logic behind it and why it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a 11-bit binary number $a_1a_2\dotsm a_{11}$, where each of the $a_i$ is a binary digit (0 or 1). In the normal interpretation of binary numbers, the value of this would be $2^{10}\cdot a_1 + 2^9\cdot a_2 + \dotsb + 2^0\cdot a_{11}$. However, when you're using the offset system, the value is taken to be $2^{10}\cdot a_1 + 2^9\cdot a_2 + \dotsb + 2^0\cdot a_{11}\ \mathbf{-\ (2^{10} - 1)}$.

In this system, the number 0 is represented by $01111111111 = 2^{10} - 1$; 4 is represented by $10000000011$; and $-4$, by $01111111011$. It is called the 'offset' system because the lowest number you can represent is 'offset' from 0 by $2^k - 1$ or in other words, you 'start counting' from a negative number. Note that $4 + (-4) = 0$ still holds, as do all the other properties of addition, because this is simply a different way of *representing* numbers, not *defining* them or their axioms.

Comment: thanks, so using this system, with 11 bits, the number $0000 0000 000$ is negative 1023 (2 ^ 10 - 1)?

Comment: @Maximus Yes. The same logic works for any number of bits.

Comment: thanks, can you please also explain how you get the following: $4$ is represented by $10000000011$; and $−4$, by $01111111011$ - working from $0111 1111 111$?

Comment: @Maximus We know that 0 is represented by $2^10 - 1 = 01111111111$. Now we can add $4 = 100$ to this like normal binary.

Comment: thanks a lot, I understand now. If you have time, can you please take a look at my [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37096796/2545680).